# How to work with 16 bit grayscale in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics

I can't find the answers to the these questions:

1. Can I use OpenCV to display 16-bit grayscale pictures? I tried `imshow()` but nothing appeared on the windows created by OpenCV.
2. How can I convert a 16-bit grayscale picture to a B5G6R5 picture? What parameter should I create `cv::Mat` with in order to store this structure? I tried `cv::cvtColor(m_cvTmp, tmp, CV_GRAY2BGR565)` but this function kept crashing. The [documentation on miscellaneous image transformations](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html) does not tell the answer.

PS: the image I want to process is already in the memory.

Comment: Make sure you put a call to `waitKey` after `imshow`. Omitting `waitKey` would be one reason for nothing at all to appear.

Comment: I did use waitKey, and the window was there but blank.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have said "nothing appeared on the screen". That's different than "a blank window appeared on the screen". The better the details in your questions, the better chance you'll have of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: @SSteve thanks, I take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `imshow`, it will automatically scale a 16-bit grayscale to 8-bit in order to display it on the screen. I tested this with the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread("pic2.jpg");

    if (!image.data) {
        std::cout << "Image file not found\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::Mat pic16bit;
    image.convertTo(pic16bit, CV_16U, 255); //convert to 16-bit by multiplying all values by 255

    // create image window named "asdfasdf"
    cv::namedWindow("asdfasdf");
    // show the image on window
    cv::imshow("asdfasdf", pic16bit);
    // wait for key
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

It displayed the grayscale image as expected. So if you are just getting a blank window, my guess is that your conversion from the other library to cv::Mat is not working correctly. For example, when I first tried to convert from 8-bit to 16-bit I got an-all black image because I forgot to multiply all the 8-bit values by 255.

As a first step in debugging I would try displaying some or all of the values in your 16-bit grayscale cv::Mat.

Also, as a general rule Stack Overflow works best if you only have a single question in your question. When there are multiple questions you will wind up with more than one valid answer but you can only accept one of them.

Comment: Thank you. I will seperate my questions next time.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to take a look at this [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html).

Your code will be like:

```
Mat imageGrey = imread("<image_name>", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

2)

```
Mat imageGrey = imread("<image_name>", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat imageBGR;
cvtColor(imageGrey, imageBGR, CV_GRAY2BGR565);
```

Does it works?

Comment: Forget to mention that the image I'm processing is already in the memory(from another lib). I created a cv::Mat conforming to its internal representation and then memcpy the data.