# Convert Color Image to 16-bit Grayscale in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, grayscale

I wish to convert a color image to a 16-bit grayscale image using C++'s OpenCV library.
I'm using OpenCV 4.1.2 and C++ 17.

I'm able to load a color image & save it as 8-bit grayscale with the following minimal example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test.jpg", -1);

    cv::Mat imageGray;
    cv::cvtColor(image, imageGray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    std::cout << "First pixel: " + std::to_string(imageGray.at<uchar>(0, 0)) + "\n";

    cv::imwrite("gray.jpg", imageGray);

    return 0;
}
```

Alongside saving the grayscale image using [`cv::imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce), I also wish to be able to access the pixels inside the image with the [`at`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f) function.

Currently I am able to convert the color image into an 8-bit grayscale using the [`cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab)  function and access the pixels inside of it using the `uchar` type template.

`test.jpg`:

[image]

`gray.jpg`:

[image]

However, I wish to convert the image into a 16-bit grayscale for a more detailed grayscale gradient.

Simply attempting to use the `ushort` type template with the `at` function instead of `uchar` results in a memory exception inside `at`.

Doing something like this instead from [the following post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13866389/12224591):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test.jpg", -1);

    cv::Mat imageGray;
    cv::cvtColor(image, imageGray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    image.convertTo(imageGray, CV_16U, 255);

    std::cout << "First pixel: " + std::to_string(imageGray.at<ushort>(0, 0)) + "\n";

    cv::imwrite("gray.jpg", imageGray);

    return 0;
}
```

doesn't cause an exception, however it appears to break `gray.jpg`:

[image]

Plus, wouldn't this also cause the image data to not be upscaled & interpolated to 16-bit properly?

What is the proper way to convert a color image to a 16-bit grayscale in OpenCV?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand the premise of your question, but you can't store a 16-bit greyscale image in a JPEG which is limited to 8-bits/channel. Maybe try PNG which can handle 16-bits/channel.

Comment: What Mark said. Also note that you screen cannot display the full dynamic range of a 16bit image. Rest of your code looks fine. What does your console output give you ? Try setting a pixel to a known value before conversion and read it back after.

Comment: Some side notes - `#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>` -- why? You're not using the C API, so including that header is useless. | `cv::imread("test.jpg", -1)` -- why use magic numbers? OpenCV has had [enumerations](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html) for this purpose for well over a decade.   `cv::imread("test.jpg", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` is so much more legible.

Comment: Beside the issue with output format, performing the cast+scaling after you've converted the BGR to an 8-bit grayscale will not yield "more detailed grayscale gradient". The input is already quantized to 256 levels of intensity, scaling those numbers will still leave you with only 256 distinct levels in the result -- they will just be spread apart, but the information content will remain the same. | Furthermore, a better scaling factor would be 256 rather than 255, since you're basically shifting left by 8. (Even better remap in a way to make `0xFF` become `0xFFFF`, but that's nitpicking here)

Comment: FF -> FFFF would take a factor of 257

Comment: as for "the proper way", first read the color image in its full depth. if that is 16 bits already, good. if not, then you need to convert it to CV_16U explicitly. then you can try cvtColor to gray.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers;
So since I cannot store a 16-bit grayscale in a JPG image, is it possible to do so using PNG? The OpenCV library should recognize the PNG format too.

Comment: have you tried? this answer could have been shorter but this site doesn't allow me to just say "yes"